# com.worklight.studio.plugin thread hangs on eclipse startup if existing worklight projects in workspace

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I have eclipse Juno and the IBM Worklight studio plugin v5.0.5 installed. The worklight documentation specific that eclipse Juno is supported, but if I create a worklight project and then close eclipse, and then try to start it up again a thread hangs on startup loading things from com.worklight.studio.plugin and I end up having to kill eclipse since it just hangs on the loading screen. It is not the same package loaded everytime either that it hangs on, it seems to be random. Here is a stacktrace from when it happened once:

```
!MESSAGE While loading class "com.worklight.studio.plugin.classpaths.ServerAPIContainer", thread "Thread[org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.StructuredRegionProcessor,1,main]" timed out waiting (5000ms) for thread "Thread[Worker-0,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "com.worklight.studio.plugin_5.0.5.20121129-1027 [882]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.reconcile.StructuredRegionProcessor,1,main]" is proceeding but "com.worklight.studio.plugin.classpaths.ServerAPIContainer" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/com.worklight.studio.plugin_5.0.5.20121129-1027/" by thread "Worker-0".
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    ... 45 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
...
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_15
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

It's a very long stack trace so I just included the parts I thought were relevant above. I can start eclipse again by deleting the worklight projects from my workspace, but this means I can only ever work on a project for a single session. I've seen other posts about this issue, but they all give the same solution of just deleting the projects. Is there any more permanent solution to this issue?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Please edit your question with a list of plug-ins you have installed in your Eclipse.

Comment: That is, plug-ins YOU have installed...

Comment: I installed the IBM Worklight studio plugin v5.0.5. That's the only plugin I installed. I installed Eclipse Juno, installed the worklight plugin, and then started using it. I haven't installed anything else.

Comment: Uninstall it and try the latest version, 5.0.6.1, however also make sure to delete from the Eclipse-workspace the WorklightServerHome folder (due to schema changes between 5.0.5 and 5.0.6.x).

Comment: Did you install 5.0.6.1? Any updates?

Comment: I think updating to 5.0.6 did it. I've been able to open and close Eclipse with a worklight project in my workspace. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: please mark this question as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall it and try the latest version, 5.0.6.1, however also make sure to delete from the Eclipse-workspace the WorklightServerHome folder (due to schema changes between 5.0.5 and 5.0.6.x).